# change date formats in text file with bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, find-replace

I have a text file with thousands of random dates in MM/DD/YYYY format. I need to convert all of these dates to YY/MM/DD. What is the quickest and easiest way to do this using bash?
Note that we will need to search for the dates because the file contains other text content as well.

Comment: You should show a representative snippet of your input file, together with what you've tried so far and how specifically you failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not even remotely robust, but you might try:

```
perl -pe 's@\b(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/\d\d(\d\d)\b@$3/$1/$2@' input
```

Comment: Thanks. This printed the correct output but how can I write it to the file?

Comment: Also, this only prints a two digit date. I need a 4 digit date

Comment: In your question, you indicate that you want YY/MM/DD, which indicates a two digit date.  If you want all four digits, move the open paren.  That is, `\d\d(\d\d)` becomes `(\d\d\d\d)` or `(\d{4})`.  If you want output in a file, redirect it.  Or, use the `-i` flag: `perl -pie ...`

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/\([0-9][0-9]\)\/\([0-9][0-9]\)\/[0-9][0-9]\([0-9][0-9]\)/\3\/\1\/\2/g' your_text_file
```

Use `-i.bak` instead of `-i` if you want to backup your file prior to modifying.

Comment: got this output

`sed: 1: "s/([0-9][0-9])\/([0-9][ ...": \3 not defined in the RE`

Comment: I forgot to add global tag, but it still doesn't explain your error. Have you copied the command precisely as above? It seems that the error is somewhere in the last group - `([0-9][0-9])`

Comment: On the off chance of ERE not activating on your `sed` try the updated pattern with escaped brackets